RuntimeError: Cannot close a running event loop with python Telegram bot
I am experimenting with OpenAI and Telegram: I just want to try a simple bot that replies to you to familiarize myself with the environment. Unfortunately I am stuck on an error that started as soon as I integrated OpenAI API calls. I have tried to remove the async from main but unfortunately I get an error about trying to access a thread while another one is running
Here is the code
import os
import asyncio
import signal
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from telegram import Update, ForceReply
from telegram.ext import Application, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, filters, ContextTypes
from openai import AsyncOpenAI
import logging
import json
from data_source import DataSource  # Assuming DataSource is now async

# Configure logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# Load environment variables
load_dotenv()

TOKEN = os.getenv("TOKEN")
ASSISTANT_ID = os.getenv("ASSISTANT_ID")
OPENAI_KEY = os.getenv("OPENAI_KEY")

# Global variables for database and OpenAI client
data_source = None
openai_client = None

async def initialize_global_resources():
    global data_source, openai_client
    data_source = await get_data_source()
    await data_source.create_tables()
    openai_client = await get_openai_client()

async def get_openai_client() -> AsyncOpenAI:
    logger.info("Initializing OpenAI client...")
    return AsyncOpenAI(api_key=OPENAI_KEY)

async def get_data_source() -> DataSource:
    logger.info("Initializing data source...")
    return DataSource(os.environ.get("DATABASE_URL"))

def next_move(action: str) -> str:
    logger.info("Initializing move...")
    return "Next move"

async def start(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> None:
    logger.info("Initializing bot...")
    dataSource = await get_data_source()
    if await dataSource.find_user_id(update.effective_user.id) is None:
        await dataSource.create_user(update.effective_user.id, update.effective_chat.id, update.effective_user.first_name, update.effective_user.last_name)
    await update.message.reply_html(
        rf"Hi {update.effective_user.mention_html()}! Here's how you can use me...",
        reply_markup=ForceReply(selective=False),
    )

async def help_command(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> None:
    await update.message.reply_text("Here's a list of commands you can use...")

async def echo(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> None:
    logger.info("Initializing echo...")
    dataSource = await get_data_source()
    client = await get_openai_client()
    thread_id = await dataSource.find_thread_id(update.effective_chat.id) 

    if thread_id is None:
        thread_response = await client.beta.threads.create()
        thread_id = thread_response.id
        await dataSource.update_thread_id(update.effective_chat.id, thread_id)

    await client.beta.threads.messages.create(
        thread_id=thread_id,
        role="user",
        content=update.message.text,
    )
    
    run = await client.beta.threads.runs.create(
        thread_id=thread_id,
        assistant_id=ASSISTANT_ID,
    )
    
    await process_openai_response(client, thread_id, run.id, update)

async def process_openai_response(client, thread_id, run_id, update):
    global waiting_time
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(waiting_time)
        try:
            run_status = await client.beta.threads.runs.retrieve(thread_id=thread_id, run_id=run_id)
            if run_status.status == 'completed':
                messages = await client.beta.threads.messages.list(  # Assuming an asynchronous OpenAI client method
                thread_id=thread_id
            )
                reply = messages.data[0].content[0].text.value
                break
            elif run_status.status == 'requires_action':
                required_actions = run_status.required_action.submit_tool_outputs.model_dump()
                tool_outputs = []
                for action in required_actions["tool_calls"]:
                    func_name = action['function']['name']
                    arguments = json.loads(action['function']['arguments'])
                    if func_name == "next_move":
                        output = next_move(action=arguments['action'])
                        tool_outputs.append({
                            "tool_call_id": action['id'],
                            "output": output
                        })
                    else:
                        raise ValueError(f"Unknown function: {func_name}")

                await client.beta.threads.runs.submit_tool_outputs(  # Assuming an asynchronous OpenAI client method
                    thread_id=thread_id,
                    run_id=run_id,
                    tool_outputs=tool_outputs
                )
            else:
                await asyncio.sleep(waiting_time)
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(f"Error processing OpenAI response: {e}")
            await asyncio.sleep(waiting_time)

    await update.message.reply_text(reply)

def run_bot():
    """Encapsulate bot running logic to allow for graceful shutdown."""
    application = Application.builder().token(TOKEN).build()
    application.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
    application.add_handler(CommandHandler("help", help_command))
    application.add_handler(MessageHandler(filters.TEXT & ~filters.COMMAND, echo))

    # Define a coroutine for stopping the application to ensure it can be called asynchronously
    async def stop_application():
        await application.stop()

    # Setup signal handlers
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    for sig in (signal.SIGINT, signal.SIGTERM):
        loop.add_signal_handler(sig, lambda: asyncio.create_task(stop_application()))

    # Start the bot
    application.run_polling()

async def main():
    await initialize_global_resources()
    run_bot()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Since we're mixing async with blocking calls, we use asyncio.run() to initiate the async part
    asyncio.run(main())

and here is the log
asyncio.run(main())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/asyncio/runners.py", line 190, in run
    return runner.run(main)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/asyncio/runners.py", line 118, in run
    return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/asyncio/base_events.py", line 653, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/kahl/Documents/Ai_projects/Eros/main.py", line 153, in main
    run_bot()
  File "/Users/kahl/Documents/Ai_projects/Eros/main.py", line 149, in run_bot
    application.run_polling()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/telegram/ext/_application.py", line 779, in run_polling
    return self.__run(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/telegram/ext/_application.py", line 983, in __run
    loop.close()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/asyncio/unix_events.py", line 68, in close
    super().close()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 88, in close
    raise RuntimeError("Cannot close a running event loop")
RuntimeError: Cannot close a running event loop
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Application.shutdown' was never awaited
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Application.initialize' was never awaited

